# Firebase Analytics not getting any data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

My firebase analytics is not working even though I know there are users on the website.
There aren't any numbers pulling through.

Here is my firebase.js code:

```
const hostname = window.location.hostname;
console.log("hostname: ", hostname);
const app =
  hostname === "localhost"
    ? initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_DEMOSTORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
        // measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
      })
    : initializeApp({
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
        authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
        storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
        appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
        measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
      });

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const analytics = () => {
  if (hostname === "localhost") {
    return;
  } else {
    return getAnalytics(app);
  }
};

if (hostname === "localhost") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}
```

Once the project was deployed and i started using the emulator, i created a conditional for analytics and that might be the problem.

I added these `<script>` lines to `index.html` today from another post but i don't think that they were the problem.

```
<body class="">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```